# Replacing part of a string with another part of that same string

Tags: bash, sed

How would I go about replacing part of a string with another part of that same string, in a bash script, using `sed`?

Comment: use the following shortcuts : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664

Comment: Do you have the string in a variable? Or in a file? What are you doing with the string?

Comment: This needs a lot more detail to be able to give a reasoned answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit too generic here.

An example:

```
sed 's/..\(.*\(..\)\)/\2\1/'
```

Would replace the first two characters of each line with the two last ones (only if there are at least 4 characters on those lines).

```
$ echo abcdef | sed 's/..\(.*\(..\)\)/\2\1/'
efcdef
```

The trick is to use `\(...\)` to *capture* what is being matched and use it in the replacement part as `\1`, `\2`...