# Replacing part of folder name with new string

Tags: bash, debian, shell, filesystems

I've found various answers that deal with this topic, e.g. [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68944/replacing-part-of-a-string-with-another-part-of-that-same-string), but they don't work for my purposes. Potentially because of the '-' character or how I am setting this up?

I am using Linux Mint (Debian), with the terminal.

I have lots of folders and subfolders that are like this:

```
folder1-Misc
folder2/afolder2name-Misc
folder2/afolder2name-SomethingElse
folder3/afolder3name-Misc
folder3/afolder3name-Blahblah
folder3/afolder3name-Anotherthing
folder4/afolder4name-Misc
folder4/afolder4name-Misc/insideafolder4name-Misc
folder5/afolder5name-Misc
folder4/afolder5name-Misc/insideafolder5name-Misc
```

I want to start at the root folder and rename all folder names containing `-Misc` with `-Docs` so the above would become

```
folder1-Docs
folder2/afolder2name-Docs
folder2/afolder2name-SomethingElse
folder3/afolder3name-Docs
folder3/afolder3name-Blahblah
folder3/afolder3name-Anotherthing
folder4/afolder4name-Docs
folder4/afolder4name-Docs/insideafolder4name-Docs
folder5/afolder5name-Docs
folder4/afolder5name-Docs/insideafolder5name-Docs
```

And I don't want to risk damaging any of the folder contents (files) or structure.

The answer link above should work, but it doesn't... I think it should be something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/*-Misc/-Docs/g' {} +
```

Would appreciate any help, hoping it's actually an easy solution :)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `rename` perl version?

Comment: The perl-based `rename` command (if that is what you are using) expects a *regular expression* on the LHS of the `s` command - in regex, `*` is a quantifier not a wildcard on its own

Comment: thanks @steeldriver that sounds like the issue! I didn't really understand how the command worked. Might you suggest what the regex should be as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using another `rename` version. The perl version is what you are looking for and usually its command is `file-rename`. In my case I had to install the package `perl-File-Rename`.

Another issue I've seen is that you are using `-type f` but this only uses `regular files` but as you said you want to rename your directories (and subdirectories). So you can use `-type d` or simply don't specify that option to be able to work with any type.

Nevertheless, I see a problem by using `-exec` directly. When you use `find . -exec`:

```
./folder2
./folder2/afolder2name-SomethingElse
./folder2/afolder2name-Misc
./folder4
./folder4/afolder4name-Misc
./folder4/afolder4name-Misc/insideafolder4name-Misc
./folder4/afolder5name-Misc
./folder4/afolder5name-Misc/insideafolder5name-Misc
./folder1-Misc
./folder3
./folder3/afolder3name-Blahblah
./folder3/afolder3name-Anotherthing
./folder3/afolder3name-Misc
./folder5
```

The output above will have problem when you want to rename the subdirectories. For example, having this:

```
/folder4/afolder4name-Misc
./folder4/afolder4name-Misc/insideafolder4name-Misc
```

will try to rename `/folder4/afolder4name-Misc` to `/folder4/afolder4name-Docs` but the next path: `./folder4/afolder4name-Misc/insideafolder4name-Misc` will cause an error because  `./folder4/afolder4name-Misc` has been renamed to `./folder4/afolder4name-Docs`.

A possible solution to that problem is by reverting the `find` output using `tac`. So your code can look like this:

```bash
find . | tac | xargs -L1 file-rename 's/(.*)\-Misc/$1-Docs/g'
```

The code above will work but I've noticed it's a bit slow.

**Solution 2:** A faster way to do this is by using `mv` but requires a few more instructions:

```bash
find . ! -path . | tac | while read -r dir; do \
[[ "${dir##*/}" =~ .*-Misc ]] && mv "$dir" "${dir%-Misc}-Docs";done
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! :)

Comment: @ratuk_ A pleasure!